# Windows 10 locks screen during use during RDP session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I am using RDP to connect to a windows 10 computer. It will periodically go to the lock screen and force me to re-enter my credentials, even when I am actively using it.

I don't have admin privileges so I am limited in my ability to change settings on the computer itself. However, other users that connect to the same machine do not havethe same issue. Is it possible that this is do to my RDP connection settings?

Comment: Could it be that you're being logged out when someone else logs in? Not all windows versions support multiple users over RDP.

Comment: Unlikely - we cannot have concurrent users, but generally it prevents the new user from logging on rather than booting the current one off. Secondly, we coordinate between ourselves and I know no one else it attempting to access it.

Comment: However, sometimes it does seems to get confused about who is logged in. Any time I connect via RDP and a user is already logged in a warning message appears ( "another user is logged in...."). This happens even if I am that other user - i.e. if I disconnected without logging out and reconnected later. In that case I can dismiss the warning and proceed to log on (as opposed to when there truly is a different user logged in, in which case my attempt to log in will fail).

Comment: "*we cannot have concurrent users*" This seems to be the core of your problem. It depends on the RDP client whether or not the warning is given that another user is already logged on. The warning might not be shown. It seems to me that while you're logged in, someone else (by accident) logs in as well, logging you off as a result.

Comment: I'm certain it's not someone else logging in for several reasons: 1) Only a handful of people have RDP access, so it is easy to check with all possible users when it happens 2) I'm always able to immediately log back in, but I get returned to the lock screen every few minutes. I have dealt with this for hours as I try to get work done (frustrating!). Another user attempting to log in would have the exact same problem as we took turns kicking each other off. As I mentioned, other users have not had the issue, and if they did I'm sure they would be equally frustrated and reach out to check.

Comment: And 3) I'm not really getting fully logged off, it's just locking the screen.

Comment: If you cannot change settings on the remote computer, maybe you can first check on your own computer: Local Group Policy/User Configuration/AdministrativeTemplates/Control Pannel/Personalization ——Enable screen saver and Password protect the screen saver whether these two policies been disabled or not configured. Otherwise, it seems there is no other setting can be made on RDP from client side

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, as I am having exactly the same issue? For me, it happens precisely 1 minute after logging in, regardless of whether I am actively using it! I can be typing mid-sentence and wham! lock screen!

Comment: Unfortunately no, this was happening in a work computer and I left the job shortly after posting this. Best of luck!